# is there possible for set rotation and scale to raster static image source in open layer 6

Tags: gis, openlayers, raster, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

- I am using open layers 6 lib for map rendering and events.
- my application needed same like this example **http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html** i.e. Example have ol.source.GeoImage..

**I have tried**

- I am displaying raster images on map using this sample code is

```
const url = imagurl;
    const extent = [0, 0, imageData.width, imageData.height];
    const projection = new Projection({
      code: 'xkcd-image',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent,
    });

    const imageLayer = new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url,
        projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
    });
```

- and i am using affine transformation lib and returns scaling, rotation and transformation..
- its giving the values

```
scaling : 327.805670381418,327.805670381418
rotation : -0.1310210334156003
transformation : 7179251.8557908312,6022627.228704552
```

**i need to add this code into ol-6 static image source**

```
source: new ol.source.GeoImage(
                {   image,
                    imageCenter: transformation,
                    imageScale: scaling,
                    imageRotate: rotation,
                    //projection: pixelProjectio
                })
```

- suggest or help on this.. thanks in advance.. and save my days..

Comment: The image size is automatically scaled to fit the specified image extent.  You can handle rotation by defining a rotated projection https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-forked-5q3e9?file=/main.js  The alternative is to preload the image, draw it rotated onto an oversized canvas big enough to fit the rotated image then use the oversized canvas as a data url.

Comment: @Mike thanks mike for replay, if i am adding OSM layer then its not working.. i.e view projection changed to **EPSG:4326**,

Comment: sample code code : ```const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  }),    
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
  })
});
map.addLayer(new ImageLayer({
  source: new Static({
    attributions: '© <a href="https://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>',
    url: "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png",
    projection: imageProjection,
    imageExtent: extent
  })
}));```

Comment: For support of EPSG:3857, EPSG:4326 and projections defined in proj4 see https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-image-z0uit  If you have EPSG:4326 coordinates the image may not be intended for that projection - KML ground overlays are rotated at their latitude of true scale in an equidistant cylindrical projection as in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4949#issuecomment-495940972

Comment: thanks @Mike, here small question, what is my extent in openlayer 6... here GeoImage have **imageCenter: transformation** but in openlayers 6 i have added as ``extent = transformExtent([translationX, translationY,
          translationX + (xScale * this.imageData.width),
          translationY + (yScale * this.imageData.height)],
          get('EPSG:3857'), get('EPSG:4326'));``
image displays on map  taken starting point as a center point (its shuld image selected center point)...

Comment: If you have center, width and height the extent is `[translationX - (xScale * this.imageData.width / 2), translationY - (yScale * this.imageData.height / 2), translationX + (xScale * this.imageData.width / 2), translationY + (yScale * this.imageData.height / 2)]`

Comment: @Mike, i am facing one more issue, if the input has some 45/180 degrees rotating image then is  issued then calculated extend and resolution image displaying very bad.. I think I need to calculate 4 extends then top-left, top-right, bottom-left & bottom-right of extend.. Version3 image source have centerOfImage and scalling and rotation. but V6 did not have that..